# How to determine the type of something in a derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, types, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

I'm making a farming simulator in which I have the base class `Produce`, which is inherited from by two classes `Crops` and `Animals`. Whenever time progresses I am looking to check through my array of `Farmland` which each have a `Produce`, and growing the `Crops` alone. To do this, I am trying to identify the type of the objects in Farmland.

```
Farmland lands[] = /* ... */;
// ...
Produce b = lands[i].getPlanted();
Produce* ptr = &b;
Crops* crops = dynamic_cast<Crops*>(ptr);
```

The above is what I have done, and then there is an if statement which occurs if `crops != nullptr`. This statement is not happening, even though I know that there are crops in `lands`, and that `Produce` has a virtual function.

Edit: I've changed `getPlanted()` to return a pointer to `planted`, and changed the above code to:

```
//Produce& b = lands[i].getPlanted();
Produce* ptr = lands[i].getPlanted();
Crops* crops = dynamic_cast<Crops*>(ptr);
```

But I'm still not having success. `crops` should be a `nullptr` if a crop was planted, correct?

Edit 2:
Unfortunately I can't use the final keyword as there are some further inherited classes after that, but the Farmland class looks like this:

```
class Farmland{
    protected:
    bool empty_or_used;
    bool unlocked;
    Produce planted;

    public:
    //constructors
    Farmland();

    //functions
    bool getEmptyOrUsed();
    void setEmptyOrUsed(bool a);
    bool getUnlocked();
    Produce* getPlanted();
    void setUnlocked(bool b);
    void setProduce(Produce newPlanted);

    //destructor

};
```

I've been looking at examples of downcasting with dynamic_cast and I just can't get mine to work.

Comment: Only pointers and references can be polymorpic. `getPlanted()` returns a **value**, which is neither of these and cannot be polymorphic. Since polymorphism is already lost in the first statement, the rest can't help. Change the function to return a pointer or a reference instead, and if it returns a reference `b` should also be a reference bound to the return value instead of assigned from it.

Comment: What does `getPlanted()` return?   If it returns a `Produce` by value, your code cannot work, since the returned object is copied and sliced as `getPlanted()` returns, and all information about the actual (derived) type of the object is lost.    If `getPlanted()` returns a *reference*, then the fix is simple.

Comment: `Produce b = …` creates an object of type `Produce`. To access derived types you need `Produce& b = …` to create a reference.

Comment: What is the definition of `Farmland`, and how are you putting different kinds of `Produce` into `lands`?

Comment: You ask in one of your edits "`crops` should be a `nullptr` if a crop was planted, correct?"   The response to that is "no" - the concept "a crop was planted" is specific to your program, not something inherent to C++.     `dynamic_cast<Crops*>(ptr)`, where `ptr` is of type `Produce *`, gives `nullptr` if `ptr` points at an object that is NOT either a `Crops` or a type derived from `Crops`.

Answer (score 0):

We need add method for determine derived in base class then override in it in derived.

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

enum ProduceType{
    animal,
    crop
};
struct Produce{

    virtual ProduceType get_type() const = 0;//this one
};
struct Animal final :  public Produce {

    ProduceType get_type() const override{
        return ProduceType::animal;
    }

    void animal_thing() const {
        std::cout << "animal thing\n";
    }
};

struct Crop final :  public Produce {

    ProduceType get_type() const override
    {
       return ProduceType::crop;
    }

    void crop_thing() const {
        std::cout << "crop thing\n";
    }
};



int main ()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Produce>> land;
    land.push_back(std::make_shared<Crop>());
    land.push_back(std::make_shared<Animal>());

    for(auto& ptr : land){//ptr is always std::shared_ptr<Produce> because we define std::vector to store it.
        if(ptr->get_type() == ProduceType::crop){//but we can still access function for get type of derived
            std::static_pointer_cast<Crop>(ptr)->crop_thing();
        }
        if(ptr->get_type() == ProduceType::animal){
            std::static_pointer_cast<Animal>(ptr)->animal_thing();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```